# Powershell Replace String CSV column

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and I have tried a few different code adjustments but keep getting stuck.

I have a CSV file from 3rd party application that I need to replace a string

| host_display_name | serice_display_name | service_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server1 | Disk / | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (86% inode=96%); |
| Server1 | Disk /Logs | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (86% inode=96%); |
| Server1 | mem | OK - 25.7% (1023324 kB) used. |
| Server2 | Disk / | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (76% inode=86%); |
| Server2 | Disk /Logs | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (56% inode=56%); |
| Server2 | mem | OK - 25.7% (1023324 kB) used. |

I would like to update it to show

| host_display_name | serice_display_name | service_output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Server1 | Disk / | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (86% FREE) |
| Server1 | Disk /Logs | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (66% FREE) |
| Server1 | mem | OK - 25.7% (1023324 kB) used. |
| Server2 | Disk / | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (76% FREE) |
| Server2 | Disk /Logs | DISK OK - free space: / 16566 MB (56% FREE) |
| Server2 | mem | OK - 25.7% (1023324 kB) used. |

Here is my Powershell Code

```
import-csv C:\Projects\Excel_Data_Powershell\Output.csv  | foreach { If($_.ou -match “inode=*%”) {$_.OU -replace “inode=*%”,”FREE”}} | export-csv C:\Projects\Excel_Data_Powershell\OutputUPDATED.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a *calculated property* with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) to recreate the **service_output** column based on your condition to replace the values inside the parentheses. For replacing them you can use [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator), as for the regex being used it's likely to be improved but this seems to do the trick. See https://regex101.com/r/TrDBXu/1 for the details.

```
Import-Csv C:\Projects\Excel_Data_Powershell\Output.csv | Select-Object *, @{
    Name = 'service_output'
    Expression = { $_.service_output -replace '(\(\d+%).*', '$1 FREE)' }
} -ExcludeProperty service_output |
Export-Csv C:\Projects\Excel_Data_Powershell\OutputUPDATED.csv -NoTypeInformation
```